# Bottom navigation bar android

Tags: android, fragment

I am trying to implement bottom navigation in fragment but some how it is not working. There is no preview for bottom navigation bar in design tab.

[image]

Here is my code for fragment xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".studentPanel.hostFragment.StudentPanelFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_st_panel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code for menu xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/profile"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/profile"
        android:title="@string/profile" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/conveyance"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/conveyance"
        android:title="@string/conveyance" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/home"
        android:title="@string/home" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/fee"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/fee"
        android:title="@string/fee_receipt" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/event"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/event"
        android:title="@string/event" />

</menu>
```

I am not able to figure where is error in this code.

Comment: u miss the most important tag i.e `Android` . Now  have u tried running the app on a device ? can u see bottomnav on device ?

Comment: You can specify ```android:layout_height="75dp"```  in BottomNavigationView in the fragment.xml file